# numpy indexing with smaller sign (<)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a question regarding indexing in numpy arrays.

Problem that arised:
While running my code I get the following error description:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

This is, as far as I understand resulting from an empty array that I give to the following line of code.

```
def rescale_linear(array, new_min, new_max):
    """Rescale an arrary linearly."""
    minimum, maximum = np.min(np.min(array), 0), np.max(np.max(array), 0)
```

array is created in the following way

`array[array < 0] = rescale_linear(array[array < 0], lower_bound, 0)`

My first question would be: is the last line of code working correctly as I intend (so do only the indexed parts of the array get changed?

My follow up question would be: If the correct parts of the array get indexed, why does the above mentioned error arise?

For your info please find enclosed the maximum and minimum value of the array as well as the chosen lower_bound.

```
max:  40.74177551269531,
min:  -0.03952115774154663, 
upper bound:  1  ,
lower bound:  -0.0009700401429297471 ,
array: [ 3.41117382e-04 -2.99751759e-04  3.48746777e-04 ...  4.14423275e+00
  4.23259640e+00  4.06539059e+00]
```

Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: You may need `np.minimum` and `np.maximum`

Comment: you can check your array. array.shape

Comment: If *array* doesn't contain elements < 0 the function is called with an empty array. Please provide a [mre] with copyable examples. Using the provided example the error is not reproducible.

Comment: Test your function is a few simple arrays.  Check the traceback of your error; if it occurs in the function (and one of the `min/max` calls, then the problem isn't with what the function returns (well, that is a problem too).   Get the function working right before you worry about using it in a larger context.

Comment: My error was solved by @MichaelSzczesny
Thank you very much :)
In the future I will strive to give reproducible code